# Extracting Data from SAP to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sap

I am using SSIS packages to extract data from SAP database tables into SQL Server tables. I am using OLEDB source/destination connections to achieve this.

The problem now is that a table in SAP has 5 Million records and its taking around 2 hours to extract this data into my SQL Server table. I have used the trunc-dump method (truncating the table in sql server and dumping data into it from SAP table) and also tried using Multiple Hash key to bring in the updated/new records.

The problem with Hash key is that it still has to scan the entire table to look for changed/new records and hence takes almost the same time as the trunc-dump method.

I am looking for a new way or changing the existing way to reduce the time taken to complete this extraction.

Comment: Does your SAP have any sort up last updated/inserted date?

Comment: @Zane Ha! I wish! I don't believe so. There is a  table in SAP which tracks all changes to all "Objects" in SAP but i dont believe i can use this because it involves going to various other tables to gather what data has been changed and to what table.